# Jython Build has no Output

Tags: netbeans, build, jython

Hey, I've been playing around with Jython a bit and I wrote the following test program:

```
from javax.swing import *
from java.awt import *
from java.awt.event import ActionListener

class JythonTest(JFrame):
    _windowTitle = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.initVars()
        self.initLookAndFeel()
        self.initComponents()
        self.initGui()

    def initVars(self):
        self._windowTitle = "Jython Test"
        JFrame.__init__(self, self._windowTitle)

    def initLookAndFeel(self):
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())

    def initComponents(self):
        label = JLabel("Hello World!", JLabel.CENTER)
        label.setFont(Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30))

        tabs = JTabbedPane()
        tabs.addTab("Test", label)
        tabs.addTab("Calculator", self.CalculatorPane())
        self.add(tabs)

    def initGui(self):
        self.setSize(400,200)
        self.setDefaultCloseOperation(self.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        self.setVisible(1)

    class CalculatorPane(JPanel, ActionListener):
        _txt1 = 0
        _txt2 = 0
        _box = 0

        def __init__(self):
            self.initVars()
            self.initComponents()

        def initVars(self):
            pass

        def initComponents(self):
            self._txt1 = JTextField(5)
            self._box = JComboBox(["+", "-", "*", "/"])
            self._txt2 = JTextField(5)
            btn = JButton("Go")

            btn.addActionListener(self)

            self.add(self._txt1)
            self.add(self._box)
            self.add(self._txt2)
            self.add(btn)

        def actionPerformed(self, ev):
            val1 = self._txt1.getText()
            val2 = self._txt2.getText()
            operation = self._box.getSelectedItem()

            val1 = int(val1)
            val2 = int(val2)

            if operation == "+":
                answer = val1+val2
            elif operation == "-":
                answer = val1-val2
            elif operation == "*":
                answer = val1*val2
            elif operation == "/":
                answer = val1/val2

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(self, "The answer is: " + str(answer))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win = JythonTest()
```

Here's my system info:

```
Operating System: Ubuntun 10.10
Netbeans Version: 6.9
```

My problem is that I can't compile the above code. It runs just fine when I click the run button, however, when I hit build or clean & build then I don't get any results. The build process runs in the bottom right corner for about half a second and then finishes. The output box opens up but it's entirely empty, even after the process ends. When I look at my project folder, nothing changes. Only two folders exist, nbproject and src. There probably should be a dist folder with a jar inside of it. Here's what's in the file structure:

```
user@computer: ~/NetBeansProjects/pythontest$ ls
nbproject  src
user@computer: ~/NetBeansProjects/pythontest$ ls nbproject
private  project.properties  project.xml
user@computer: ~/NetBeansProjects/pythontest$ ls nbproject/private
private.xml
user@computer: ~/NetBeansProjects/pythontest$ ls src
pythontest.py  setup.py
```

All I did to set up was install netbeans from the debian package (quite a while ago) and set up python/jython through the NetBeans python plugin. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that it doesn't really work like that; I'm not aware of any IDE or tool support for packaging jython programs.

Usually what I do is just make a shell script that says:

```
java -cp "the/classpath/;" org.python.util.jython myscript.py
```

I've found that is the most foolproof way to run a jython program, and has saved me many headaches from not-working `.jar` files during development.

---

That said, there are methods of packaging jython programs in standalone `.jar` files, if that's what you want.

The best resource that I've found is the [Distributing Jython Scripts](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts) page in the [Jython FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq), which describes a few different techniques for distributing jython scripts.

I usually only use the methods described there when "publishing" a program.